# Date search in sqlite not working

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, datetime

I'm trying to search a database for tomorrows date which then proceeds to an email function.

```
def send_email():
currentdate = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
nextday = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow = str(nextday.strftime("%d %m %Y"))
with sqlite3.connect("school.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT DateIn FROM MusicLoan WHERE DateIn = ?",(tomorrow,))
    row = cursor.fetchall()[0]
    if str(row) == str(tomorrow):
        cursor.execute("SELECT StudentID FROM MusicLoan WHERE DateIn = ?", (currentdate))
        ID = cursor.fetcone()[0]
        cursor.execute("SELECT email FROM Student WHERE StudentID = ?",(ID))
        email = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        fromaddr = email
        toaddr = "danielarif@blueyonder.co.uk"
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = fromaddr
        msg['To'] = toaddr
        msg['Subject'] = "Music Reminder"
        body = "A reminder that your music is due in tomorrow"
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.ehlo()
            server.set_debuglevel(1)
            server.starttls()
            server.ehlo()
            server.login("danielarif123@gmail.com", "DanR0bJ0nes3")
            text = msg.as_string()
            server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
            server.quit()
            print("Email Sent Successfully")
            send_email()
        except smtplib.SMTPException:
            print ("Error: unable to send email")
            send_email()
```

my problem is is that it gets to the row = cursor.fetchall()[0] and then stops.
How can I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't "stop", it gets to the if condition on the following line and since that can never be true, it falls through to the end.

`fetchall()` will give you a list of tuples, that is a list of all the rows that match where each row is a tuple of all the columns. So, your `[0]` index actually gives you a tuple with a single element, the data column. But `str(row)` will be something like `('2015-04-29',)`, which is not equal to `'2015-04-29'`.

You need to *iterate* over the results from `fetchall()`, and do your checking each of those rows.

However that still won't fix your problem, as you have a deeper logic error. You select the rows where DateIn is equal to tomorrow. But then you check that DateIn is equal to *today*. Again, that can never be true.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that logic error there, my bad when writing this quickly. It has been edited now.

How can I iterate these results?

Comment: With a for loop: `for row in cursor.fetchall()`, then `if row[0] == str(tomorrow)`, although with your revised code that could never be false.

Comment: Also you may want to change your GMail password, now you've posted it publicly on the Internet...

Comment: Oh, that was my old gmail anyway

Answer (score -1):

cursor.execute("SELECT DateIn FROM MusicLoan WHERE DateIn = ?",(tomorrow,))

and use fetch one method cursor.fetchone()

Refer the https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html for more examples

Comment: If I do that, I get this error
cursor.execute("SELECT DateIn FROM MusicLoan WHERE  DateIn= ?",(tomorrow)) sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The  current statement uses 1, and there are 10 supplied.